# python getting syntax error in except

Tags: python

I am new to python and just been playing with the database API. I am getting an invalid syntax error in the exception except block comma. I can't figure out any syntax mistakes. Below is the code I am using

```
import time
import MySQLdb
import sys
import urllib2

#f = open("../", 'r')

try: 
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="test", passwd="test",db="test")
    cur = db.cursor()

except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit (1)

finally:
    cur.close()
    db.close()
#f.write('amal')
#f.close()
```

Comment: Are you trying to run this with Python 3 perhaps? You are using Python 2 libraries here, so even if you were to correct the syntax it won't work.

Comment: Also, including the traceback makes it much easier for us to help you :)

Comment: Try `except MySQLdb.Error as e:`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Martijn Pieters.. Yes, i am using Python 3..

Comment: Andrei Horak ... Thanks... Let me try it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is correct *for Python 2*, which would be the correct version given the fact that you tried to import `urllib2` here.

For recent Python versions the `except` syntax was updated, and the old syntax no longer works in Python 3. The correct syntax would be:

```
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
```

but you'll need to fix what Python version you are running this with *or* use the correct libraries for Python 3. That means using `urllib.request` and installing `MySQLdb` for your Python 3 installation first.